# Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' error

Tags: webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js

I want to use [picomatch](https://github.com/micromatch/picomatch) package in the browser.

But some ES6 features used in the package didn't go well in some old IE browser, and I think I can use babel to polyfill it.

This is my webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            ["@babel/preset-env"]
          ],
          sourceType: "unambiguous"
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

after I require the package in my code, I got:

> Cannot asign to read only property '.js' of #

I also tried the plugins in babel:

```
plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
```

but with no luck.

I used the package in a Nuxt project, after I add the package to [transpile module](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#transpile) setting, same error happened.

I really don't know how to fix it.